# Why setting breakpoint in VSCode hangs a pop up windows?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, firebase-authentication, angularfire, vscode-debugger

I have a "helloWorld" Angular app. And all I do is to leverage Firebase/AngularFire for sign in and sign out. If I use `redirect`, everything is fine and I can set breakpoints to debug the application. But if I use `popup`, the application will work in Debug only if I don't have any breakpoints. But if I set breakpoint, the pop up will be hung, looks like it's stopping at an invisible breakpoint. Strangely enough, the breakpoint can be anywhere of which the code path will not be actually hit. Then, after the timeout, the popup windows will be gone on the screen, but Debugger shows the thread is still there in the call stack. GUI becomes unresponsive until restarting the debugger. Sometime, the first time works, but it will fail in the second time when I sign in again.

**Question**: How come setting breakpoint in VSCode change the behavior of a pop up windows?

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "port": 9222
    }
  ]
}
```

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { firebase, firebaseui, FirebaseUIModule } from 'firebaseui-angular';
import firebaseConfig from '../../firebaseConfig.json';
import {
  AngularFireAuthModule,
  AngularFireAuth,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

const firebaseUiAuthConfig: firebaseui.auth.Config = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInOptions: [firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',
  tosUrl: '<your-tos-link>',
  privacyPolicyUrl: '<your-privacyPolicyUrl-link>',
  credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.GOOGLE_YOLO,
};
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.result.sdkConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FirebaseUIModule.forRoot(firebaseUiAuthConfig),
  ],
  providers: [AngularFireAuth],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**src/app/app.component.html**

```html
    <firebase-ui></firebase-ui>
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="this.signout()">
      Signout
    </button>
```

**src/app/app.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'helloWorld';

  constructor(private _authService: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signout(): any {
    this._authService
      .signOut()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('sign out');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('I have an error' + e);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the "exact" same problem. Would appreciate if someone has insights into this!